# How to set an interface as the type for a state?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

Here is my React functional component that fetches data from an API and stores it in the `drinks` state.

The data that's fetched is an array of objects. Each object has a key `strCategory` and a string as its value. So I want to make a TypeScript interface for this data (that's stored in the drinks state). However, I'm not sure where to add that interface (`Drink`). This is what I'm trying:

```
function App() {

   interface Drink {
     strCategory:string;
   }

   const [drinks, setDrinks] = useState([{strCategory:''}]) // <---how do I add the interface Drink to this state?

   const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list');
    const jsonData = await response.json()
    setDrinks(jsonData.drinks);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
  }, [])


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h2>Drinks</h2>
        {drinks.map((item, index) => {
          return <Link className='App-link' key={index} to="/category?c=">{item['strCategory']}</Link>
        })}
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `useState<Drink[]>(...)`? It's an _array_ of drinks. Have a look at e.g. https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react, and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [inspect the typings of `useState`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/0eab8010f41fbec067bd3cd2a1a45d56bac014f3/types/react/index.d.ts#L892-L898), it accepts a generic type that allows you to specify the type of data:

```js
const [drinks, setDrinks] = useState<Drinks[]>([{ strCategory: '' }]);

// Alternatively if you're more comfortable with using Array<...>
const [drinks, setDrinks] = useState<Array<Drinks>>([{ strCategory: '' }]);
```